# empty output of casted pointer scope

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

Code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  char* ptr = nullptr;
  int a = 10;
  int* tmp = &a;
  ptr = (char*)&a;
  std::cout<<&a<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<tmp<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<ptr<<std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```sh
0x7ffee733535c
0x7ffee733535c
```

I just want to figure out the background reason.
Plz do me a favor.